# ASP.NET Core API - Different methods on the same route and HTTP verb

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am currently working on a .NET Core API using roles-based authorization.

In some of the endpoints, it is necessary to implement custom logic based on the users role. Rather than creating separate routes for different roles, I would prefer an implementation where the frontend can use the same endpoint regardless of the current users role.

Ex. to update a users information:
A admin should be able to update any users information, and any other role should be limited to only changing their own user data only.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPut]
public UserDto UpdateUserAdmin(Input input)
//Can update any user based on Id from input.

[Authorize] //Match any role other than admin
[HttpPut]
public UserDto UpdateUserDefault(Input input)
//Can update logged in user only. Id from token.
```

My initial thought was that this routing would be solved using the Authorize attribute, but as far as I can tell, this attribute cannot be used to resolve ambigious matches on the same route?

While looking for a solution, I came across action constraints.

However, I ran into some problems where the claims from the token were not yet set as I ran my constraint. (Might be a problem in the order of my middleware?)

Anyway! Is Action Constraints the way to go for these kind of issues?
Or is there another solution for this in .NET Core?

Comment: I think you should use policy based authorization . You can write custom policies and add to controller level and action level

Comment: if you think, this might answer you problem please choose this as the answer

Comment: If you want  the frontend can use the same endpoint regardless of the current users role, and resolve ambigious matches on the same route, how about  firstly getting the current users role, then using `if (role = xxx)` to judge the  current users role, then  implement custom logic based on the users role in the  the same endpoint.

Comment: @QingGuo This is what I've been trying to avoid, as I would rather structure the logic in different methods.

Comment: @thanzeel Way, way late! But do you mind making your comment into an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @DatTronGuy, i have done it, thanks even though its late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use policy based authorization . You can write custom policies and add to controller level and action level